# Send Multiple Variables back to the screen using Navigator.pop

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am sending back arguments using Navigator.pop by wrapping them in a class. But in previous screen printing the results say "Instance of 'FilterArguments' "
`var result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/filters');`
and send back data like this. 
`Navigator.pop(context, FilterArguments(upperRange: 1000, lowerRange: 200, beds: 21));`

Comment: Hi Anas, please provide the relevant pieces of your code so that people can help you best :)

Comment: @UjCorb check the edited one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hellow Anas,

Welcome to stackoverflow, I see that you are also relativelly new to flutter also!

When sending back arguments in `Navigator.pop(context, arguments)` you can do multiple things. Sending back a custom `Class` is my way to go (as you have already done) so that is great.

However, when you try to print a class, you will always get the `Instance of 'Something'`. This is the correct behaviour, and it means that you got what you sent back.

If you want to check what is inside that class, I suggest putting a `breakpoint` and debug to it, however I can assure you that you got your data!

**Edit with examples**

```
class Fruit {
  final String name;
  final Color color;
  Fruit({this.name, this.color});
}

//Popping the info
...
Navigator.pop(context, Fruit(name: 'banana', color: Colors.yellow));
...

//Retreiving the info
...
final Fruit selectedFruit = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/fruit-selector');

//Using the info
print(selectedFruit.name);
```

Comment: Bro How can I access data?

Comment: ```print(results.upperRange)``` the getter upperRange is not defined

Comment: following your code, it should be print(result.upperRange) without an s

Comment: It worked bro, thanks. 

```var result =  await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/filters');
   FilterArguments resultofFilterArgumentsType = result;
   print(resultofFilterArgumentsType.upperRange);```
 I had to store it in a variable of my models class type.